# Why am I not getting $user_name from the db?

Tags: php

```
I am not getting any  output from `" $_SESSION['name'] = $user_name;" or $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['in_email'];`
```

It running on MariaDB. Seems I am missing something, try a good few things. But ran out of ideas. A hit or to would be appreciated.

```
    if ($stmt = $link->prepare('SELECT user_id, user_password_hash, user_name FROM users WHERE user_email = ?')) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $inemail);
        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->store_result();

    }

    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $user_password_hash, $user_name);
        $stmt->fetch();


            if (password_verify($_POST['in_password'], $user_password_hash)) {

            session_regenerate_id();
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
            $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['in_email'];
            $_SESSION['id'] = $user_id;
            $_SESSION['name'] = $user_name;
            header("Location: ../index.php");
            exit;
```

What am I overlooking ? Any hit would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which can be tested by others. Also take the [tour] and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.

Comment: Why do you use the `session_regenerate_id()` function? What are you trying to accomplish with the function call? And how do you transfer the session id from the client to the server?.

Comment: Yeah you are right, thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you are running `session_start();`

This creates a session or resumes the current one based on a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or passed via a cookie.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php